# mysql table alias and table real name in the same query

Tags: mysql

in the following query i get `#1054 - Unknown column 'zzAir_Reservations_201201.id' in 'where clause'`. Why is that?

```
    SELECT `id`
    FROM
        `reservations` AS `res`
    WHERE
        `reservations`.`id`='0'
```

This is a simplified query, the original one is much more complicated.

This worked at some point in the past, but i've update the mysql server in the last few weeks i think this is a new "feature"

I know it makes no sense in making an alias if its not used, but it doesn't really make sense to limit the usage of the original table because i aliased it. I couldn't find any reference in the manual

Comment: Why not just do "WHERE `id` = '0'"? Maybe you need to de-simplify your question a bit. Not enough information.

Comment: because the original question uses multiple tables, all of them having an `id`. Just try and run this in mysql, and you'll get an error

Comment: Yes, I did get an error. I checked on 5.1.41 and I also checked on another server running 5.5.20. Both have the error. I guess you will have to change your queries or downgrade.

Comment: Buttle Butkus is correct, and probable issue you have... when using an alias for a table, use that "alias" all the way through on all columns, ESPECIALLY if multiple tables and could otherwise be ambiguous to the next person looking at your queries for maintenance purposes.  You have where "Reservations", but "res" as the alias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an `alias` for the table and you use the original name of the table that's why an error (`Error Code: 1054`) was generated.

Instead of

```
SELECT `id`
FROM
    `reservations` AS `res`
WHERE
    `reservations`.`id`='0'
```

Use

```
SELECT `id`
FROM
    `reservations` AS `res`
WHERE
    res.`id`='0'
```

Answer (score -1):

I write most of my queries from PHP where often I don't even know what the table name will be.

So I always have them aliased as t1, t2, etc. Then my WHERE clauses always use t1.'a', t2.'a', etc and everything works.

e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT `$source_table`.`$category_field`, `$support_table`.`$subcategory_field` WHERE `$t1`.`$id_field` = `$t2`.`$id.field`;
```

or something like that.

Hopefully you don't have too many queries, because it sounds like you might have a big mess on your hands.

Comment: I alias them also, but this an old codebase.. I have no ideea how many queries are written like this. The problem is that i have no way to detect them at this moment. The thing is that i'm not sure why this is a problem, or if its a feature(it might be a version-specific thing, as i dont have another sql server to test on)